# How to store image captured using camera.takePicture(null,null,mPicture) so that it can be displayed it in next activity?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am making a custom `camera` application in android. I capture the `image` using

`camera.takePicture(null,null,mPicture)" and "Camera.PictureCallBack()`

I want to store the `image` taken from the `camera` so that I can display it in the next `activity`. How can it be done?

```
    Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);

            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
};



private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "MyCameraApp");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
            + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: Show the code of the callback to begin with. As we see no image now.

Comment: @greenapps I have added the code. Kindly review it. Thanks.

Comment: So you know already how to save the image in the data byte array. Wel what goes wrong? And as there is no code in your catch blocks you will never know if someting goes wrong. And you forgot to post the code for  getOutputMediaFile().

Comment: @greenapps this is the code which I have used. How can I get the image inside the imageView in the next activity of my application?

Comment: You should first tell us if the image indeed is saved as file. Does your code work so far? If it works than you did not need to post all that code.

Comment: @greenapps I restarted my device, and then the folder appeared in which the images are being stored.

Comment: `and then the folder appeared` It is unclear where it would appear. You are not very informative. If the file is there you can use it in the next activity of course.

Comment: Right, you must invoke the [MediaScan intent](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery) so that the new image be known to MediaStore (and Gallery). But you don't need the picture to be known system-wide to open it in another activity in your app, just as @Rahul [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47696507/192373).

Answer (score 2):

Pass uri in extras of your next activity intent

```
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_USING_CAMERA) {
            try {
               Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
               i.putExtra("uri",outputFileUri);
               startActivity(i);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Exception", ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then retrieve image in your second activity

```
Uri = getIntent().getExtras("uri");

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;

final Bitmap capturedimage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri, options);
imgPreview.setImageBitmap(capturedimage );
```

Answer (score 1):

TO open Camera

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE_USING_CAMERA);
```

Then need to implement onActivityResult to get the data.

```
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_USING_CAMERA) {
            try {
               final File file = new File(outputFileUri.getPath());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Exception", ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can take the image form the `file` path to display in the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CameraView](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) to implement the custom camera in very simple way which gives you the functionalities to capture image and video. You can see the [DEMO](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView/tree/master/demo) where it the [CameraActivity](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/otaliastudios/cameraview/demo/CameraActivity.java) tooks the picture and [PicturePreviewActivity](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/otaliastudios/cameraview/demo/PicturePreviewActivity.java) and [VideoPreviewActivity](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/otaliastudios/cameraview/demo/VideoPreviewActivity.java) are use to preview the picture and video taken in CameraActivity.